# How can I tell if I'm doing a create or an update with django generic views (CreateView vs UpdateView) from my template?

Tags: django, django-templates, django-generic-views

I'm sharing the same template for my `CreateView` and `UpdateView` using django's generic views. I want the "submit" button in my template to say "Add" when I'm using the `CreateView` and "Update" when I'm using the `UpdateView`. Is there any way in my template to distinguish which view is being used (`CreateView` vs `UpdateView`)?

I know I could use a separate template using `template_name_suffix` and put the common stuff in a separate include or something but just wanted to see if there was a way to do it without creating a separate template.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

When creating a new object, `object` will always be None, at the moment the template is rendered. You could check for the existence of `{{ object }}` in your template:

```
{% if object %}Update{% else %}Add{% endif %}
```

Comment: Better proposal instead of overriding :)

Answer (score 2):

Override get_context_data and add a flag in your view:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
    context = super(YourClass, self).get_context_data(**context)
    context['create_view'] = True
    return context
```

Change YourClass to your Class View name

Then in your template you can:

```
{% if create_view %}
```